# JQuery Text Field Calculator

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I am trying to use JQuery to update the deposit field each time a number is inputted in the total text field. I think maybe I need to parse the data? Any help would be appreciated

Contact-Form-7

```
<label> Name </label>
    [text your-name] 

<label> Total </label>
    [number total min:1 class:total-amt] 

<label> Deposit </label>
    [number deposit id:deposit-amt] 

[submit "Send"]
```

JQuery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $total_field = $('.total-amt'),
        $total_deposit = $('#deposit-amt');
$total_field.on('input', function(e) {
        $total_deposit.val(($total_field * 0.4));
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to multiply your text field (`$total_field`) by `0.4`. What you want to do is get its *value* (`$total_field.val()`) and multiply it by `0.4`.

Meaning, this line:

```js
$total_deposit.val(($total_field * 0.4));
```

has to change to:

```js
$total_deposit.val($total_field.val() * 0.4);
```